# Annotations, markers or flags with additional information box on mouseover in HighCharts.js

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, marker, flags

I have following series set in chart options:

```
series: [{
    pointStart: new Date().getTime() - (60000 * 60 * 24 * 14),   // start two weeks ago
    pointInterval: 60000,   // minute
    data: [50,100,150,200,50,100,150,200,50,100,150,200,50,100],
    id: "InitialSerie",
    name: "InitialSerie"
}, {
    type: 'flags',
    shape: 'circlepin',
    data: [
        { x: new Date().getTime() - (60000 * 60 * 24 * 14) + (60000 * 4), text: 'Highcharts version 1.0 released', title: '2.7' }
    ],
    showInLegend: false,
    onSeries: 'InitialSerie'
}]
```

Result is correct, as following picture.

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1443.jpg)

But I need to display some additional information on hover to this flag. Like in the following picture:

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlqQ6.jpg)

It should works according to documentation and demo. No errors appears, so I am really wondering, what is bad ...

Comment: It works for me, see http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/36eswseo/

Comment: Oh man, thanks a lot, it works! I realised I don't have tooltip enabled.

Comment: Thanks to ewolden, now it is solved. It was needed to enable tooltips in chart options too.